# New Table vs New Database via LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-2

Currently i'm developing a WPF + ASP.Net Application
WPF at Desktop role as Club Manager while
ASP.Net is used to allowed user register as club member
Database plan to host at shared host SQL Server 2008
Both will connect to ASP.Net via LinQ to SQL

Now the problem i confuse and cannot solve that is
Club is not only one
while there might 1 snooker club and 2 days later may built up another pool club
May i know how can i create a new * for while new club is setting up ? 
**will create a new table inside the database will better than create a new database ?**

will both application ASP.Net and WPF connect via LINQ will caused them a security holes ?
any better suggestion ?

Thank you for reply and sorry if this post violate site rules ~.~
because of currently rush for assignment and need to know clearly on what technology is available to me =D

Comment: Do you guy prefer to connect them via LINQ ? or any other better suggestion ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're getting at.  But I think you mean, how can you have multiple "clubs".

The answer to that depends on your requirements.  For example, do idividual clubs need to run on different servers (possibly in different hosting facilities?).  If so, you need seperate databases for each club.

If the application will always run on your servers, and you have complete control over them, then you can design your database with a club selection column, and typically make it part of your primary key.  No need to even create a new table.

The only reason you would create a new table is if you needed different data from one club to another, and even then there are other ways to solve that problem.

Comment: i get what you mean...yes, i host on a single server and i have complete control. what i get from your idea is all data have a key to link together to say that record at Club_ID of 1 is belonging to snooker and Club_ID of 2 is belonging to pool =D Thank you so much and wonder is there any problem on execute them through LINQ ?

Answer (score 1):

If your database design is correct, you should only need to create a new set of records not a new database or a new table.

Comment: what you mean by new set of record ? because many club got to record member who access to that club respectively... can be created as record to hold em'll ??

Comment: Thank you and wish to vote up but sadly my reputation is limited ~.~